I am using cypress but can't detect installed browsers
I am new to cypress
I have just simply installed node and cypress and after using it with npm init
I used npx cypress open
It worked but the only browser available for e2e was "electron" even though i have Chrome and Mozilla
How can i make this work?
Opening cypress using ubuntu cli
npx cypress open
I tried downloading chrome again
I also tried putting the chrome to program files x(86) it didn't work
help

If the automatic detection is not working, you can specifically add the browser path.
See Launching by a path
From the command line:
cypress run --browser /usr/bin/chromium

Or the browser details can be inserted into the config file.
Here is a simpler version of the example given in the documentation. I set the Brave browser as the only option (Brave is not normally detected by Cypress)
cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.browsers = [
        {
          name: 'Brave',
          channel: 'stable',
          family: 'chromium',
          displayName: 'Brave',
          version: '126.1.67.119',
          path: 'C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe',
          majorVersion: 126,
        } 
      ]
      return config
    },
  },
});


Adding also the Chrome Beta browser
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.browsers = [
        {
          name: 'Brave',
          channel: 'stable',
          family: 'chromium',
          displayName: 'Brave',
          version: '126.1.67.119',
          path: 'C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe',
          majorVersion: 126,
        },
        {
          name: 'chrome',
          family: 'chromium',
          channel: 'beta',
          displayName: 'Chrome Beta',
          version: '127.0.6533.17',
          path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe',
          minSupportedVersion: 64,
          majorVersion: '127'
        },
      ]
      return config
    },
  },
});


